# GNU GRUB Version 2.02 beta 2-9 while booting from USB

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

I attempted to install the latest version of Linux Ubuntu Studio, with previously installed Ubuntu 14.04. Installation procedure went fine, it was only at the finish, when something collapsed, I failed to write down or take a picture of what the problem was.

Now, when i try to boot from USB, it stucks on this error

```
GNU GRUB Version 2.02~ beta 2-9 

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB 
lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible 
device or file completions.

grub>_
```

None of the options in Boot menu are not successfull. Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'll refer to that prompt as a 'grub rescue' crash.  You can use the grub commands with steps provided in this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148042/81664

I have used those steps in the past and it works.  However, I usually use a different set of steps that also works.  The steps below that I'm using involves updating grub and reinstalling grub.

The reinstalling will incidentally repair and problem glitches in the original install that is causing the crash.  The update with find all installed OSes and add them to the boot menu.

You can most likely remedy this by manually installing grub on your desired HD.

Boot to a live try Ubuntu session, then run the following at a terminal prompt:

```
a) sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt # Make "sdaX" the partition that has Ubuntu install (i.e. /dev/sda2)
b) for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt/$i"; done
c) sudo chroot /mnt
d) update-grub
e) if no errors skip this "e" section
     grub-install /dev/sdX (sdX is the hard drive that has linux installed (i.e. /dev/sda)
     update-grub 5) Reboot the system
```

After you have performed the manual steps be sure to set your computer bios to have your desired boot drive as the default boot device.

Comment: If i had this instruction before I would be running (or at least tested ) Ubuntu in 32 bit EFI but the upgrade to W10 has prevented booting from USB nowadays :/

Comment: Windows 10 won't prevent booting to the USB.  That is a BIOS option.  All of Windows 10's operations and configurations are on the Harddrive.  The BIOS options are run before the harddrive options are read.  You could set your BIOS to give priority to booting from the USB over booting from the Harddrive.  Also, the steps above can be performed from an Ubuntu install DVD.

Comment: And how would I get an EFI32 bit grub disc?