# How to fix GRUB

Tags: grub2

I have Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot with Windows 8

So I decided I need to reinstall Ubuntu to increase its space.

I went to Windows 8 and deleted the Ubuntu partitions and now I can't turn on my computer or anything and I keep getting [image: this GRUB message] every time.

My highest priority is not to touch other partitions.

I already have tried this:

[GNU GRUB Version 2.02 beta 2-9 while booting from USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541402/gnu-grub-version-2-02-beta-2-9-while-booting-from-usb)

Comment: If you're reinstalling Ubuntu, go ahead and do that. That generally makes the system bootable. Choosing on the DVD/USB boot menu to try Ubuntu before installing and running `gparted` will let you resize partitions and so on.

Comment: i already resized my partitions from windows and deleted ubuntu partitions too and i cant even log in to do anything

Comment: @Olathe you can make your comment an answer. I think it's the best solution for this situation. There are many similar questions but nothing exactly the same.

Comment: @coding, do you have the Ubuntu install DVD/USB?

Comment: yes i have on usb i inserted but couldnt open it because of this massege

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? If UEFI you can go into UEFI and change default boot to Windows or use one time boot key like f10 or f12. If BIOS you need to install Windows boot loader to MBR. You can do that from your Windows repair flash drive with fixMBR. Or install a Windows type boot loader from Ubuntu live installer. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on If UEFI: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From ["Boot Ubuntu live USB from GRUB2 prompt"](https://tuxdiary.com/2014/11/18/boot-ubuntu-live-usb-grub2-prompt/):

1. At the `grub` prompt, type `ls` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Pick one of the partitions listed.
3. Type `ls (hdX,Y)`, replacing `X` and `Y` with what showed up for the partition you picked, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. If it looks like a Windows drive, go back to step 2 and pick a different partition.
5. If it looks like Linux's root directories, run the following, replacing `X` and `Y`:

   ```
   set root='(hdX,Y)'
   chainloader +1
   boot
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried Supergrub 2 rescue? Using the site 
[Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) you can load the ISO you want onto a USB drive - The ISO you want is [Supergrub2](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/)

It does mean you need another computer to prepare the USB but you should be able to boot and hopefully effect a repair.

Good luck!

It is only by messing things up that you learn how to put things right!