# Fix GRUB menu for dual boot Windows 10 / Ubuntu 18.04 on separate hard drives

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

After following the steps in this post [How can I prevent Windows from overwriting GRUB when using a dual-boot machine - Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68581/), I'm now presented with the "GNU Grub version 2.02" black screen upon attempted boot.

I have tried this: [GNU GRUB Version 2.02 beta 2-9 while booting from USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541402/), this: [How to Fix - GNU GRUB version 2.02 error Ubuntu - Minimal BASH Like Line Editing is Supported - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Il73tKhZf7Y), and boot-repair.

Boot-repair gives me ***"Please close all your package managers (Software Center, Update Manager, Synaptic, ...). Then try again."*** message when nothing is opened. Here is the bis: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/t8yhwRnpW9/.

I'm completely at a loss for what else to try and I need to be able to boot into Ubuntu to work (no chance to reinstall).

Comment: It looks like sdc has an UEFI install of Windows and sdb has a BIOS install of Ubuntu. Your sda is just a NTFS data drive? You cannot mix UEFI and BIOS, if you want to boot from grub. You can boot only from UEFI boot menu and may have to turn on/off UEFI/legacy boot mode, though most now recognize which way you are trying to boot. UEFI & BIOS are not compatible and once you start in one mode you cannot switch, or grub only boots other installs in same boot mode. Re-install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode and use gpt partitioning.

Comment: sda is an external drive (not sure why). Windows is installed on sdc. Ubuntu is installed on a partition of sdb (sdb3) and the remainder of the drive is used as storage space for windows. I can't reinstall Ubuntu as I've been using it for a while and it has all of my work / customizations. Before I attempted to fix the boot menu I would just select the correct drive at boot, which was a minor annoyance. If I could go back to this I would be fine, I just need to be able to boot into Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you running boot-repair from a bootable USB?

Comment: Reboot live installer in BIOS mode and add Boot-Repair. Only use Advanced mode, not any auto fixes that Boot-Repair suggests. And choose Ubuntu install partition and only MBR of that same drive. Plugging in an external drive often changes drive order. Best to leave that unplugged while fixing.

Comment: You've mixed up your disk format types where you have Windows on sdc drive as a GPT disk and Ubuntu on sdb disk as an MBR running in UEFI mode. It's been said many times not to mix the 2 types as it leads to grub issues. Best thing is to convert the sdb disk to a GPT format, but you will lose all data on that disk when you do so.

Comment: @oldfred this did it, thank you! I did not realize using boot-repair in UEFI live-usb would not work.

Comment: You can convert a MBR drive to gpt & vice-versa. But have to reinstall grub and with gpt need a bios_grub partition for grub to correctly install in BIOS boot mode or an ESP - efi system partition for UEFI boot. I started converting drives to gpt in 2010 and all drives now are gpt. Most also are now UEFI boot. Converting to or from GPT - must have good backups.
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html & GPT Advantages (older 2010 but still valid)  see post#2 by srs5694:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1457901